# How to create a smooth transition in jqueryui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery toggle that removes a series of divs from a page:

```
        $("a#list-mode").click(function() { 


        $("a#list-mode").toggleClass("rm-toggle");
        $("a#map-mode").toggleClass("rm-toggle");
        $("div.rm-ta").toggleClass("rm-toggle-ta");
        $("div.rm-address").toggleClass("rm-toggle");
        $("div.rm-short-filters").toggleClass("rm-toggle");
        $("div.rm-filters").toggleClass("rm-toggle");
        $("div.rm-book").toggleClass("rm-toggle");
         $("#list-fix-pos").toggleClass("col-lg-3");

         });
```

At the moment, this creates quite a "jerky" page update; is there any way to make this smoother, and/or potentially apply an effect to all the transitions so they smooth in at once?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean with "jerky", do you mean that fadeing animation is inconsistent or possibly that other (visible) divs on your page behave erraticly???

Answer (score 0):

to remove divs from page visualy nice i tend to use jquery built-in functions
like:

```
$("#div").fadeOut();
```

or

```
 $("#div").slideUp();
```

they both end up with display:none style on them and u can show them useing reverse functions:

```
$("#div").fadeIn();
```

or

```
 $("#div").slideDown();
```

for same effect

Comment: If I apply this effect to all the elements it would still be jerky. How can I smooth this code in its entirety?

Comment: He's right. You'd better use transition functions instead of messing up toggle with CSS3.